# App crashing when tested on physical device

Tags: firebase, debugging, crash, admob, appstore-approval

I recently finished a project I've been working on for the past few months. I archived and uploaded the app to the app store, after having no bugs in the simulator. I received a message from the developer team at Apple telling me my app was rejected, as

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 11.4.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, we were unable to install your app for review. Please upload a new binary

You would think by this message the app is having some connectivity issues. My app only communicates to the internet via Firebase, and admob. I have created a new xcode project, copied almost everything over and checked the code for errors multiple times, with no success. I have submitted multiple new builds without firebase and admob. The tests always work flawlessly in the simulator, but never install through testflight. It just downlaods, and then stops.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This can be a lot of things. You should really get a physical device to test it in because then you will see which errors (if any) Xcode will present you.

This does not seem like it has anything to do with AdMob or Firebase in particular.

Comment: thats the thing - I dont get any errors when running on a physical device but app seems to